# Configure sound hardware, how to?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have as main goal to switch to ubuntu/linux full time except for games more or less. Although ubuntu works quite well out of the box there is one thing I have a small issue with and not entirely sure how to solve it. I currently have 3 different sound devices to work with but I only want to use one of them.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.1 x64 desktop version by the by.

The onboard soundcard is the one I prefer it's also connected to the front jack on my tower case. But when i plug in my streamer in the front jack I don't get any sound really seems rather to be tied to another soundcard. And I have no real idea on how to change that in ubuntu.

Here is the list of my sound devices found by aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: DGX [Xonar DGX], device 0: Multichannel [Multichannel]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: DGX [Xonar DGX], device 1: Digital [Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
zorkel@Queans-Fury:~$
```

I believe the front jack is tied up to xonar DGX instead of intel pch.

In windows when I plugin a device I get a popup message asking me if I plugged in front speaker or headset. In linux I get no such question.

The main use is to plugin a streamer so I can send audio to my hearing aid device. And when it's plugged in I would also like to mute my stereo which is connected to it through the backpanel.

Some help and guidance would be quite welcome thank you.

The motherboard is for the record:
Asus maximus ranger viii

Link to my motherboards details if desired.
https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-RANGER/

> ***** amixer -c0 contents *********
>
> numid=41,iface=CARD,name='Front Headphone Jack'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=off
>
> numid=35,iface=CARD,name='Front Mic Jack'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=off
>
> numid=37,iface=CARD,name='Line Jack'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=off
>
> numid=40,iface=CARD,name='Line Out CLFE Jack'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=off
>
> numid=38,iface=CARD,name='Line Out Front Jack'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=on
>
> numid=39,iface=CARD,name='Line Out Surround Jack'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=off
>
> numid=36,iface=CARD,name='Rear Mic Jack'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=off
>
> numid=42,iface=CARD,name='SPDIF Phantom Jack'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=on
>
> numid=34,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
> : values=on
>
> numid=33,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=87,step=0
> : values=39
> | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
>
> numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=off,off
>
> numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=87,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
>
> numid=49,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---RW-,values=2,min=0,max=255,step=0
> : values=254,254
> | dBscale-min=-51.00dB,step=0.20dB,mute=0
>
> numid=25,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Boost Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
>
> numid=13,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=off,off
>
> numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Front Mic Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
>
> numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=on,on
>
> numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Front Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=87,step=0
> : values=87,87
> | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
>
> numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=on,on
>
> numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Surround Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=87,step=0
> : values=87,87
> | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
>
> numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
> : values=on
>
> numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Center Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=87,step=0
> : values=87
> | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
>
> numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
> : values=on
>
> numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='LFE Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=87,step=0
> : values=87
> | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
>
> numid=27,iface=MIXER,name='Line Boost Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
>
> numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=off,off
>
> numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
>
> numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=on,on
>
> numid=24,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch',index=1
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=off,off
>
> numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=63,step=0
> : values=38,38
> | dBscale-min=-17.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
>
> numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume',index=1
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=63,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=-17.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
>
> numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Loopback Mixing'
> ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2
> ; Item #0 'Disabled'
> ; Item #1 'Enabled'
> : values=1
>
> numid=32,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Default PCM Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
> : values=on
>
> numid=28,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
> ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
>
> numid=29,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
> ; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
> : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
>
> numid=30,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
> ; type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1
> : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
>
> numid=31,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
> : values=off
>
> numid=18,iface=MIXER,name='Auto-Mute Mode'
> ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2
> ; Item #0 'Disabled'
> ; Item #1 'Enabled'
> : values=1
>
> numid=44,iface=MIXER,name='Beep Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=off,off
>
> numid=43,iface=MIXER,name='Beep Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
>
> numid=19,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source'
> ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
> ; Item #0 'Front Mic'
> ; Item #1 'Rear Mic'
> ; Item #2 'Line'
> : values=0
>
> numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='Input Source',index=1
> ; type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=3
> ; Item #0 'Front Mic'
> ; Item #1 'Rear Mic'
> ; Item #2 'Line'
> : values=0
>
> numid=26,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Boost Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
>
> numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Switch'
> ; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2
> : values=off,off
>
> numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='Rear Mic Playback Volume'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=31,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | dBscale-min=-34.50dB,step=1.50dB,mute=0
>
> numid=46,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | container
> | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
>
> numid=45,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
> ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=6,min=0,max=36,step=0
> : values=3,4,0,0,0,0
> | container
> | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
> | chmap-fixed=FL,FR,RL,RR
> | chmap-fixed=FL,FR,RL,RR,FC,LFE
>
> numid=47,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=1
> ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | container
> | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
>
> numid=48,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=2
> ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
> : values=0,0
> | container
> | chmap-fixed=FL,FR

Hopefully this is reasonably easy to read.

Not sure if I understood correct you did ask for this output and not that of just amixer?

Comment: Can you configure the correct output in `pavucontrol`?

Comment: In a sense I can, when I plugin headsets or my streamer the stereo gets muted, headsets gets marked as plugged in but no sound at all. Otherwise the port line out (plugged in) is showed as active.  Switching between the ports: line out/ headphones has no impact on behaviour both get routed to the stereo.  Did disable the other 2 sound devices in pavucontrol. @CL

Comment: Show the output of `amixer contents`.

Comment: @CL Done updated with the information you requested I believe.

Comment: These are the controls of the DGX. Please show the output of "amixer -c0 contents".

Comment: @CL My apologies, still very new to linux trying my best to find my way around and the proper tools for the job. Much more used to windows and guis. But added the requested information.

Comment: Run `alsamixer -c0`, and try to unmute "Headphone", and/or disabling "Auto-Mute Mode".

Comment: @CL It didn't quite work thought I'm quite sure why, just not sure how to solve it.   When I installed ubuntu the front audio connector was connected to the onar sound card due to the fact that when I tried to install linux previously it didn't detect my onboard sound card.   Albeit that was debian jessie so might explain it.  So to my surprise ubuntu found my onboard soundcard and as it has superior sound in windows I do prefer to use it. But that probably stands to reason why it's linked to the xonar device which would be c0 instead of c1.  Should I reinstall or just remove the Xonar?

Comment: If the output is connected to the Xonar, select it in `pavucontrol`, and run `alsamixer -c2` and change `Analog Output`.

Comment: @CL My apologies, seems I wasn't all to clear, the output WAS connected to the Xonar card during the installation of Ubuntu.

But to my surprise Ubuntu found the onboard soundcard to my surprise eventually I moved the output from Xonar to the onboard soundcard. But the system still think it's connected to the Xonar card.

Screenshots of Pavucontrol

http://imgbox.com/g/6ko6rsfZa7

Comment: Also running pavucontrol in console gives me these error messages.

zorkel@Queans-Fury ~> pavucontrol
(pavucontrol:5943): IBUS-WARNING **: Unable to connect to ibus: Could not connect: Connection refused

zorkel@Queans-Fury ~> sudo pavucontrol
(pavucontrol:6467): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/zorkel/.config/ibus/bus is not root!

(pavucontrol:6467): IBUS-WARNING **: Unable to connect to ibus: Could not connect: Connection refused